# Change order of files listed in Solution explorer from alphabetical descending to ascending?

Tags: sorting, visual-studio-2012, solution-explorer

In the Visual Studio 2012 solution explorer, I see a list of all my script files.  On my old computer's Visual Studio 2012, the files were listed alphabetically ascending.  However, on my new computer the files are listed alphabetically descending.  How can I switch the sort order of the scripts back to being listed in ascending alphabetical order?

Thanks in advance.